# What is the difference between Component.name and Component.gameObject.name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm playing with C# in Unity and I've noticed that sometimes different aproaches are giving me the same results.

Let's say that I have an array of game objects and I want to access their names using for loop. What the difference between calling two lines below? I debuged both of them but they appear to be the same.

- myArray[i].name
- myArray[i].gameObject.name

Comment: Since myArray is an array of gameObjects it's going to be the same. It would make difference when say your array is an array of Transforms then it would make sense to use the second one.

Comment: @GhAyoub even then it is the same since `Component.name` just is a wrapper property that basically returns `this.gameObject.name;` ;)

Comment: @derHugo absolutely true !  It would be the same when getting the name but would make difference when wanting, for example, to deactivate the object.

Comment: well, sure because you can't deactivate a `Trasnform` ^^ My point was rather also answering OP: Unity has some redundant properties to make your live easier -> Yes the same reference/property can be reached on multiple ways

Answer (score 0):

In your case both lines do the same because you have [] of GameObjects, and all components on GO have prop name what is just name of gameobject.

But if you will have [] of game components then you must use "gameObject" for deactivation for example.